# matplotlib animation change the xlim by data but the xtick not change

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to use animation to dynamic display the data ,but when I change the axes' xlim by the set_xlim() function ,the axes' xticklabel not changing whith tick moving . How can I do ,to make the xticklabel and the tick change with the data of the xlim ? `my using code`

```
def data_update():
    .......
    axes1.set_xlim(limx_min,limx_max)
    ......`
    return .....,axes1

def animate(data):
    ......`
    return .....,axes1

anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,data_update,init_func = init,interval = 26,blit = True )
```

picture1 time1

[image]

picture2 time2

[image]

Comment: please Edit your post and send your code

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here, and it's hard to say which one is responsible for the undesired behaviour:

**A.** Your call to FuncAnimation does not make sense. You provide 3 different functions, while you'd only need two. One for animation, one for initialization. You can even leave the initialization out in most cases. However, you don't have an argument for setting the frames. So consider putting everything that should be animated into `animate`, delete `data_update` and provide an argument to `frames`:

```
animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=100, init_func = init,interval = 26)
```

**B.** You might consider not to use blitting. Set `blit = False` in the animation. 
If you really need blitting, you need to provide a minimal example in the question in order to make sure, it's working correctly.